# How to skip lines matching a string

Tags: sed

I'm modifying some files and want to skip all lines that have the strings `def` or `page.` on them. How do I do this in sed?

Comment: This is a task much better suited to `grep`...

Comment: @Chris Agreed.  egrep -v 'def|page' <filename> is a start.

Comment: Do you want to skip the lines by not updating it or by not even presenting it at the output at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here. Could you provide input and output? Is this part of a sed stream or are you literally rewriting `grep`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to apply some changes to various lines except some line matching a regex, right? In this case, let us suppose I have the following file:

```
$ cat file
this is a def
this has no d e f
this is a page by the way
but this is no p a g e as we know ito
```

We want to replace all `this` by `that` but ignore the lines containing by `def` or `page`. So first we delete the lines starting with `def` or `page`:

```
/def/d;/page/d;
```

Then we apply our operation as usual:

```
s/this/that/g
```

The result is:

```
$ sed '/def/d;/page/d;s/this/that/g' file
that has no d e f
but that is no p a g e as we know ito
```

But if by "skip" you mean "do not apply my operations", just negate the address:

```
$ sed -E '/(def|page)/!s/this/that/g' file
this is a def
that has no d e f
this is a page by the way
but that is no p a g e as we know ito
```

The above statement correct. Interestingly, the 'or' operator is associated with "extended regular expression." So you must specify -E for "extended regular expression" because sed, by default, uses only "basic regular expressions."

For example, the following statement doesn't work:

```
$ sed -e '/(def|page)/!s/[A-Za-z_]*login[A-Za-z_]*/page.&/g' < file > new_file
```

But this statement below works:

```
$ sed -E '/(def|page)/!s/[A-Za-z_]*login[A-Za-z_]*/page.&/g' < file > new_file
```

Comment: Another way of avoiding modifying the `def` or `page` lines is `-e '/def/n;/page/n'` (which also avoids using not-strictly-portable extended regular expressions).  The `n` command prints the current line and moves to the next line.

Comment: That is an awesome way, Jonathan! I was trying to convey some method for avoiding the extended regexes and considered to do something like `/def/!{/page/!s/this/that/g;}` file. It is a cumbersome solution however, and yours is much better. One more sed pattern to have in mind :)

Comment: @jonathan suggestion doesn't work if you have consecutive lines that match. For instance if the first `this is a def` line is repeated, it will only skip the first but do the change on the second. I think you need to do `-e '/def/n;/def/b;/page/n;/page/b'`

Comment: @DaveGriffiths: you're right — drat!  Manual says _"`[2addr]n` Write the pattern space to the standard output if the default output has not been suppressed, and replace the pattern space with the next line of input."_  It doesn't add the all important 'and start the next cycle' which I had assumed.  The fix is to replace the `n` with `{p;d;}` which prints the line and deletes it, with the `d` command having _"`[2addr]d` Delete the pattern space and start the next cycle."_

Comment: Can someone add an answer explaining how to use the information in these comments?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK You can't (easily) negate matching lines with `sed`, but something like will almost work:

```
sed '/\([^d][^e][^f][^ ]\)\|\([^p][^a][^g][^e]\)/ s/foo/bar/' FILE
```

it replaces `foo` with `bar` on the lines which does not contain `def` or `page` but catch is that "matching" lines must be at least 4 char long.

A better solution is to use `awk`, e.g.:

```
awk '{ if ($0 !~ /def|page/) { print gensub("foo","bar","g") } else { print } }' FILE
```

HTH

Comment: on the contrary, it is easy to negate a regex address in sed! Just put a `!` at the front of the regex, such as in `/def/!s/foo/bar/`.