# How do I skip lines using sed?

Tags: sed

I want to perform a sed substitution globally in a file.  However I want to skip certain lines:
- those where the substitution would occur after a !
- those containing a comma (,)
- those containing the word "parameter" (lower or upper case)

How do I do this?

Comment: Post sample input and output.

Comment: Do it have to be `sed`.  Other program may do it better? And -1 since you did not post what you have tried.

Comment: Why `sed`?, you could do this easily in awk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip lines matching a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684857/how-to-skip-lines-matching-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Your first exception is not trivial to implement, but maybe you can rephrase it as part of the substitution? So to replace "foo" with "bar" except on those lines, I'd go with

```
sed '/parameter\|,/!s/^\([^!]*\)foo/\1bar/'
```

(Some `sed` dialects will want more or fewer backslashes.)

`/parameter\|,/!` will only select lines which do not match this regular expression.

`s/^\([^!]*\)foo/\1bar/` will substitute "foo" with "bar" provided that "foo" is not proceded by an exclamation mark. The leading text is captured into a back reference `\1` and basically replaced with itself.

The case insensitive matching requires an ugly regex in `sed` -- `[Pp][Aa][Rr][Aa][Mm][Ee][Tt][Ee][Rr]`. For anything more complex, maybe switch to Awk or Perl, which provide better facilities for complex matching as well as much more readable code.