# Removing lines with only a single comma

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have search for a way to do this, I have found similar questions but nothing that matches this.

I have a cvs file with the following text:

```
nfoabc,infidel
infoghi,infojkl
,
,
,
inferno,infopqr
infoabc,infodef
,
,
,
```

The desired output is:

```
infoabc,infidel
infoghi,infojkl
inferno,infopqr
infoabc,infodef
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to filter the lines with a single , and no other characters… I think this is where I'm having difficulty.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip lines matching a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684857/how-to-skip-lines-matching-a-string)

Comment: Thanks everyone. What I was doing wrong was not writing it back to a file, ideally, I'd have it overwrite the existing file but I can deal with this. Thanks!

Comment: @cducasse: `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`. Replace `cmd` with whatever command you want to execute.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep -v '^,$' file
infoabc,infidel
infoghi,infojkl
inferno,infopqr
infoabc,infodef
```

or for this particular input file where there's either 1 or 0 commas:

```
$ grep '[^,]' file
infoabc,infidel
infoghi,infojkl
inferno,infopqr
infoabc,infodef
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *edit* the file, you can always use `ed`:

```
ed -s file <<< $'g/^,$/d\nw'
```

Comment: Cool! Can you do it with MS-DOS `edlin` too? ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have no idea what `edlin` is, sorry `:(`.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!/^,$/' file

nfoabc,infidel
infoghi,infojkl
inferno,infopqr
infoabc,infodef
```