# Replace substring only in lines that match a pattern

Tags: bash, sed, bsd

How can I run a replacement in sed only when part of a line I *don't* want to replace includes one of a list of substrings?

For example, say, the substrings used to mark lines I want to replace are `123`, `456` and `abc` in the following sample input:

```
# jdggsdihdf, 123
# ljhkhkjh, 789
# fagdfhgghjasfa, 456
# jsajspjsdighishxc, abc
# jgasdjGA, def
```

Thus, only those lines should be modified, and the lines with `789` or `def` should be left alone:

```
Replaced text, 123
# ljhkhkjh, 789
Replaced text, 456
Replaced text, abc
# jgasdjGA, def
```

---

I know how to do simple `s/foo/bar/` replacements, so I could do `s/^# .*,/Replaced text,/`, but I don't know how to do that only when the line also matches a string in one of the fields I *don't* want to change with the replacement.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: ...with a title specific to that individual question. Our goal is to build a knowledgebase with every question one might separately have individually asked; when you combine multiple questions to a post, we then lose the ability to select the best, most canonical instance of each individual question and build a single answer to it (vs having a potentially-conflicting answer on each instance). Moreover, a generic title means others with the same problem *can't find your question*, making it less useful to others.

Comment: Should I remkae this?

Comment: I edited it. Hope thats better?

Comment: can you clean it up?

Comment: Much better, yes. (Ideally, you'd also show what you tried and how it failed, or explain what part of the problem was messing you up -- for instance, "I know how to do a string replacement, but not how to do that only on lines that also match a specific regex").

Comment: I believe what you want is `sed -re '/123\|456\|abc/{ s/^# .*,/Replaced text,/ }'`; I'll add that as an answer if we have a successful reopen vote.

Comment: You worded it much nice. Thanks. Sorry for bad english. It still says it is on hold. Is this bad?

Comment: So, it takes 5 people to vote to close a question (usually, there are some exceptions -- elected moderators can operate on their own, and certain kinds of close votes can be done by people with lots of reputation in a tag), so it takes 5 people to vote to re-open it again after it's been improved. I already voted to re-open it; perhaps others will as well.

Comment: OTOH, a reopen vote might not be needed here, since we already do have a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684857/how-to-skip-lines-matching-a-string that covers the topic. (The question isn't clear there if they want to delete or ignore non-matching lines, so the answer covers both).

Comment: (oops, I should have had *either* the `-r` flag *or* the backslashes before the `|`s in the approach suggested in my comment above, but not both -- sorry about that!)

Answer (score 1):

***For 1st question:***

```
sed 's/^#.*,/replaced_text/'  Input_file
```

***For 2nd question:***

```
sed 's/\, [^ ]*/,/' Input_file
```

To modify the Input_file itself use `sed -i` option, to take backup of Input_file use `sed -i.bak` option too.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct?

Comment: @Chris, did you try it? I am getting exact output as shown by you by both of them.

Comment: I didnt try it. you dont specify the patterns so I am not sure how it could work?

Comment: @Chris, without testing how could you say? I tested them before posting it here.

Comment: I just edited the second example to better show what I was trying to explain.

Comment: @Chris, so what my 2nd solution will do it will remove everything from first comma to first space which is coming after it(in spite of hard coding the strings I choose to do it).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I've tried to edit the question in a way that more clearly expresses the OP's intent -- perhaps that makes it clear where this answer could be edited to be more responsive?